# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1923 (note 1 of 2)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1923 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are two entries.

Here is the first one:

[image]

The handwriting is quite clear and I have this transcription:

> Del 25 de Agosto al 4 Sepbre. (Septiembre) presto servicio de
> concentración en Málaga.

Translation:

> From 25 August to 4 Sep. (September) I serve as a concentration officer in Malaga.

1. Are we missing a word or have I made an error? Because it is using the word "I" instead of "he".
2. Is there a relevant article about this time period in Malaga?

Comment: I see this: https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/45617302 Possibly related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation uses "I" instead of "he" because you missed a tiny accent mark. It's "prest**ó**" (third person, past) instead of "presto" (first person, present). Also he was no officer. He did concentration service duties in Málaga during the mutiny described in [the newspaper that you found](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/45617302).

More info about the events (in Spanish) [here](https://www.diariosur.es/malaga/motin-malaga-tropas-20171125195138-nt.html) and [here](https://www.laopiniondemalaga.es/malaga/2017/11/27/tiempos-guerra-malaga-28112842.html).

An excerpt of the first article by Ángel Escalera published in Diario Sur (25/11/2017)

> Detenciones de soldados.
>  Casi a la vez, un grupo de soldados acudió a
> la estación de ferrocarril con la intención de esperar un tren
> militar. Otros insubordinados recorrieron las calles dando gritos y
> asustando a la población. Hubo varias personas heridas con
> contusiones. Ante el desarrollo de los acontecimientos, las
> autoridades civiles y militares tomaron medidas para acabar con el
> conflicto y conseguir que Málaga recobrase la normalidad. Así, fuerzas
> del Regimiento Borbón, formadas en patrullas al mando de un oficial,
> persiguieron a los sediciosos y detuvieron a todos los que
> encontraron, aunque algunos se dieron a la fuga y se escondieron en
> distintos puntos de la ciudad. Otros se refugiaron en el campo. **Allí
> los persiguió y detuvo **la Guardia Civil****. Entre los arrestados estaban
> el cabo del Regimiento de Navarra José Sánchez Barroso, que fue
> considerado el cabecilla de la rebelión, y 20 soldados autores de las
> agresiones contra el suboficial muerto y un capitán.

Comment: Ah, something as little as an accent causes such a change to the meaning. Thanks for spotting that. And i appreciate the links to the articles. I'll translate then online and have a read tomorrow.

Comment: I do not think it is worth composing a question for the second note for 1923. It clearly reads *En el puesto de Fuente Obejuna finió el año.*. So tomorrow I will process the 1924 and 1925 notes. There is one for each year and they are both similar in content I think.